# Marshal object using JAXB incorrect Tag name

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb, marshalling

I have Root object ProcessConsignmentRequest

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "ProcessConsignmentRequest", propOrder = {
    "request"
    })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "ProcessConsignmentRequest", namespace ="http://tempuri.org/")
public class ProcessConsignmentRequest {{
@XmlElementRef(name = "Request", namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
protected JAXBElement<ConsignmentRequest> request;
```

When I Marshal this object. The object'tag of ConsignmentRequest default set to "ConsignmentRequest" but I want it exactly is "Request".
Some suggestion for me. Thanks .
This xml result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. As I discovered, JAXBElement doesn't look to the name in your @XmlElementRef annotation. It looks to the QName that you pass to it's constructor. In my case it was

```
new JAXBElement<>(someService.getServiceName(), Some.class, someInstance)
```

I changed that code to the line below and got what I wanted:

```
new JAXBElement<>(new QName("MyElementName"), Some.class, someInstance)
```